# Manejo array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy empezando con Javascript, estoy intentando hacer este ejercicio, pero no logro resolverlo:

Mostrar los números del 10 al 0 (109876543210),en la siguiente línea los números del 9 al 0 (9876543210) y así sucesivamente hasta acabar mostrando sólo el 0.

Solo he conseguido sacar todos los números, pero no sé como ir mostrando menos dígitos del array:

```javascript
var datos = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
var numArray = '';
var numArray2 = '';

for (var i=0; i<datos.length; i++) { 
    numArray = numArray + datos[i]; 
}

alert ('Valores del array ' + numArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando métodos de Array:

```js
function mostrarNumerosHasta(hasta){
  Array(hasta+1).fill()
                .map((x,i)=>hasta-i)
                .map((x,i,arr)=>arr.slice(i).join(''))
                .forEach(x=>console.log(x));
}

mostrarNumerosHasta(10);
```

1. `Array(11)` crea un array vacío de 11 items
2. `fill()` llena todos los items (en este caso sin valor definido, pero es irrelevante)
3. `map((x,i)=>hasta-i)` cambia los valores para que sean del 10 al 0
4. `map((x,i,arr)=>arr.slice(i).join(''))` reemplaza cada item por el array del paso anterior, cortándolo desde cada una de las posiciones hasta el final y los concatena, generando un array con los valores: `"10987654321"`, `"987654321"`, ..., `"0"`
5. `forEach(x=>console.log(x));` imprime cada uno de los valores.
   Este último paso no es del todo necesario, se puede imprimir dentro del (4) pero lo agregué por claridad.

---

Más info en

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array

Answer (score 0):

Con el metodo [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)

```js
     var datos = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];

     for (var i=0; i< datos.length; i++) {
         var datos2 = datos.slice(i, datos.length)
         var numArray = '';
         for (var z=0; z<datos2.length; z++) { 
             numArray = numArray + datos2[z]; 
         }
         console.log('Valores del array ' + numArray);
     }
```

Comment: El `for` interior se puede reemplazar por `datos2.join('')`